# APNS certificate on server

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

After I generate the APNS certificate and private key for the use of push notifications...

Where do I install this specifically on my Windows server? 
Is it inside the solution?
Is it somewhere inside IIS?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to have some piece of software that will send notifications. Part of its configuration will be providing it the key and certificate. This is not a standard part of IIS. You need some additional software.

Comment: For testing Download WAMP for windows and MAMP for Mac . Then create a php script for sending notification . and run the script . If you wanna learn how to do that I will answer

Comment: I understand that the Windows server (in this case) sends a push notification to the APNS server. Other team members tell me they have that in place. I'm simply asking here... where on the server does the APNS Certificate and Private Key get installed? My guess is that you can simply right click on the files in the Visual Studio solution and add the .p12 certificates. Is that right or no?